# Adding content body to client email

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

In my web application i have link "contact Us" this link is:

```
<a href="mailto:somemail@somemail.com" title="contactus">contact us</a>
```

My question is: is there a way to put into the opened email body some content? 
I mean if user is click on the link, and his default email is opened, in this steep is there a way to open his default email with some content in body? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mailto:somemail@somemail.com?subject=Contact us&body=Message goes here!
```

Comment: Hi! Do you know how i can add html entities for content? something like this :Report&body=From Page :<a href='http://some_url' target='_blank'>PageName</a> in .Net mvc3

Comment: Sorry, but that's impossible.